# Add back-end filtering to SharePoint BCS assembly

Tags: sharepoint, bcs

I have an external list built from a BCS .net assembly.

It's been in production for a year or so and works well but now the volumes are rising.  We implemented paging which has made significant improvments but after adding paging, we lost filtering.

To be more specific, filtering works, but only against the single page dataset.  i.e. I can filter on the 10 or 100 displayed records.

This is not what the business want.  I need to find a way to pass the filters back to my backend system (which both have filtering support.

Any tips are appreciated.

Kind Regards,
Ashley